# Update Delivery Date (Custom Field) in screen Invoices and Memos of Acumatica ERP System using webservices API

Tags: c#, web-services, api, acumatica, erp

I have create new additional field in header of screen Invoices and Memos, please refer to the screenshot below.

[image: delivery date custom field]

this below is DAC:

```
#region UsrDeliveryDate
public abstract class usrDeliveryDate : IBqlField{}
  [PXDBDate()]
  [PXUIField(DisplayName="Delivery Date", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]

  public DateTime? UsrDeliveryDate
  {
      get;
      set;
  }

  #endregion
```

And then I used this code below to update this delivery date using webservices API:

```
try
        {
            sCon.getLoginInv(context);
            AR301000Content kon = context.AR301000GetSchema();
            var command2 = new Command[]
            {
                kon.InvoiceSummary.ReferenceNbr,
                kon.InvoiceSummary.Type,
                kon.InvoiceSummary.CustomerOrder,
                kon.InvoiceSummary.DeliveryDate
                //kon.InvoiceSummary.DueDate,
                //kon.InvoiceSummary.Customer
            };
            var filter = new Filter[]
            {
                new Filter()
                {
                    Field = new Field
                    {
                        FieldName = kon.InvoiceSummary.CustomerOrder.FieldName,
                        ObjectName = kon.InvoiceSummary.CustomerOrder.ObjectName
                    },
                    Value = "CNSE/17-III/00023"
                }
            };
            var result = context.AR301000Export(command2, filter, 0, false, true);
            foreach (var ax in result)
            {
                DeliveryDateClass delivDate = new DeliveryDateClass();
                delivDate.refNbr = ax[0].ToString().Trim();
                delivDate.type = ax[1].ToString().Trim();
                delivDate.custOrder = ax[2].ToString().Trim();
                delivDate.deliveryDate = ax[3].ToString().Trim();
                //delivDate.dueDate = ax[4].ToString().Trim();
                //delivDate.customerID = ax[5].ToString().Trim();

                kon.InvoiceSummary.Type.LinkedCommand = null;
                kon.InvoiceSummary.Type.Commit = false;
                var command = new Command[]
                {
                        new Value { Value = delivDate.type, LinkedCommand = kon.InvoiceSummary.Type},
                        new Value { Value = delivDate.refNbr, LinkedCommand = kon.InvoiceSummary.ReferenceNbr},

                        new Key
                        {
                            ObjectName = kon.InvoiceSummary.DeliveryDate.ObjectName,
                            FieldName = kon.InvoiceSummary.DeliveryDate.FieldName,
                            Value = "='" + delivDate.deliveryDate + "'"
                        },

                        new Value { Value = "4/20/2017", LinkedCommand = kon.InvoiceSummary.DeliveryDate },
                        kon.Actions.Save
                };
                context.AR301000Submit(command);
                sCon.getLogout(context, contextUntyped);
            }
            return "Update Success";
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(x.Message);
            return "FAILED";
        }
        finally
        {
            sCon.getLogout(context, contextUntyped);
        }
```

I ty to update delivery date for this transaction below.

[image]

But I have an error message like this below.
[image]

If I used the same code above for transaction with Doc Type = "Invoice" it works, but it doesn't work for transaction with Doc Type = Credit Memo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was the reason to modify **Type** field by setting **LinkedCommand** to `null` and **Commit** to ***false***?

```
kon.InvoiceSummary.Type.LinkedCommand = null;
kon.InvoiceSummary.Type.Commit = false;
```

The sample below works just fine without any modifications to the **Type** field:

```
Screen context = new Screen();
context.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
context.Url = "http://localhost/StackOverflow/Soap/AR301000.asmx";
context.Login(username, password);
try
{
    Content invoiceSchema = PX.Soap.Helper.GetSchema<Content>(context);
    var commands = new Command[]
    {
        new Value
        {
            LinkedCommand = invoiceSchema.InvoiceSummary.Type,
            Value = "Credit Memo"
        },
        new Value
        {
            LinkedCommand = invoiceSchema.InvoiceSummary.ReferenceNbr,
            Value = "AR004776"
        },
        new Value
        {
            LinkedCommand = invoiceSchema.InvoiceSummary.Description,
            Value = "Test"
        },
        invoiceSchema.Actions.Save
    };
    context.Submit(commands);
}
finally
{
    context.Logout();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ruslan, it works. I just clear the kon.InvoiceSummary.Type.LinkedCommand = null; and
kon.InvoiceSummary.Type.Commit = false; But why if I used modification in Type field it works using DocType = Invoice, but it doesn't work with all type except "Invoice" ?

Comment: Because Invoice is the default Type.

Comment: understood. Thanks for your answer Ruslan :)

Comment: Hi Ruslan, I really Sorry for mention you again. But I have an urgently question, if you don't mind, could you please give me references to solve my issue in this question's link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44195954/insert-adjustments-document-in-screen-ap302000-of-acumatica-erp-through-web-serv?noredirect=1#comment75407873_44195954  

I already wait for any questions, but no answers can solve this issue.
Many thanks if your are willing to give me references to solve this issue.